# module parse failed when include jquery and bootsrap

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am adding SB Admin template in my .vue file,

When I include `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` in my `main.js` it returns following error:

> ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery.js Module parse failed:
>   E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\jquery.js
>   Unexpected token (7586:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7586:0)
>       at Parser.pp$4.raise (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
>       at Parser.pp.unexpected (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
>       at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:727:47)
>       at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:981:25)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseFunctionBody (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2105:24)
>       at Parser.pp$1.parseFunction (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1065:10)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1810:19)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (E:\swapnil\sanskar\front\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)  @
>   ./src/main.js 19:0-54

I am using jquery version: `2.1.4` and bootstrap version: `3.3.7`, can anyone please tell me solution for this?

Comment: What is there at this line: `./src/main.js 19:0-54`

Comment: in webpack.base.conf.js i have 


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES2015 syntax inside main,js

npm install jquery --save-dev

```
import $ from 'jquery';
// or
import jQuery from 'jquery';

// export for others scripts to use
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Same goes for bootstrap or any other dependency from npm